# If I write an application with MeteorJS, will I expose my code to the viewers visiting my page?

Tags: javascript, meteor, server-side-scripting

I was just wondering if meteorJS exposes the code to the viewer on the browser like the javascript or can one write a pure server side program with it like in Python and render only the result in the browser?

Comment: the server will run on node and the frontend will run on react/angular/vue ect.
it is true that you have to take care on what is shared between server and client. because the code on prod is minimized it should not be a problem to have business logic there in most cases. however you have to be careful with private access keys.

Comment: There are several packages on atmosphere for server side rendering, many are frontend agnostic.

Comment: If you are asking if server side code is exposed then the answer is no the code is not exposed. Client side code is always available regardless of what framework/library is used. Meteor does automatically obfuscate the code on the client when in production.